# Generate random number outside of range in python

Tags: python, random, range

I'm currently working on a pygame game and I need to place objects randomly on the screen, except they cannot be within a designated rectangle. Is there an easy way to do this rather than continuously generating a random pair of coordinates until it's outside of the rectangle?

Here's a rough example of what the screen and the rectangle look like.

```
 ______________
|      __      |
|     |__|     |
|              |
|              |
|______________|
```

Where the screen size is 1000x800 and the rectangle is [x: 500, y: 250, width: 100, height: 75]

A more code oriented way of looking at it would be

```
x = random_int
0 <= x <= 1000
    and
500 > x or 600 < x

y = random_int
0 <= y <= 800
    and
250 > y or 325 < y
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `random_int`?

Comment: A simple approach would be to create a list of all possible `x` values so in this case `[0 .. 499, 601 .. 999]`, then randomly select an index from within this list. Same approach works for `y`.

Comment: Generate x and y first. Check if (x,y) inside the small rectangle. If yes, bump up x and y so that they are outside. (Similar to rounding off)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It's pseudo code

Comment: "Is there an easy way to do this rather than continuously generating a random pair of coordinates until it's outside of the rectangle?" - actually, [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is a well-established technique that's extremely efficient as long as the rejection probability isn't too high. If the exclusion box takes up most of the screen, a 2-stage weighted draw probably works better, where you break the allowed region into 4-8 rectangles, pick a rectangle with probability proportional to area, and draw a point from the rectangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It requires a bit of thought to generate a uniformly random point with these constraints. The simplest brute force way I can think of is to generate a list of all valid points and use `random.choice()` to select from this list. This uses a few MB of memory for the list, but generating a point is very fast:

```
import random

screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800
rect_x = 500
rect_y = 250
rect_width = 100
rect_height = 75

valid_points = []
for x in range(screen_width):
    if rect_x <= x < (rect_x + rect_width):
        for y in range(rect_y):
            valid_points.append( (x, y) )
        for y in range(rect_y + rect_height, screen_height):
            valid_points.append( (x, y) )
    else:
        for y in range(screen_height):
            valid_points.append( (x, y) )

for i in range(10):
    rand_point = random.choice(valid_points)
    print(rand_point)
```

It is possible to generate a random number and map it to a valid point on the screen, which uses less memory, but it is a bit messy and takes more time to generate the point. There might be a cleaner way to do this, but one approach using the same screen size variables as above is here:

```
rand_max = (screen_width * screen_height) - (rect_width * rect_height) 
def rand_point():
    rand_raw = random.randint(0, rand_max-1)
    x = rand_raw % screen_width
    y = rand_raw // screen_width
    if rect_y <= y < rect_y+rect_height and rect_x <= x < rect_x+rect_width:
        rand_raw = rand_max + (y-rect_y) * rect_width + (x-rect_x)
        x = rand_raw % screen_width
        y = rand_raw // screen_width
    return (x, y)
```

The logic here is similar to the inverse of the way that screen addresses are calculated from x and y coordinates on old 8 and 16 bit microprocessors. The variable `rand_max` is equal to the number of valid screen coordinates. The x and y co-ordinates of the pixel are calculated, and if it is within the rectangle the pixel is pushed above `rand_max`, into the region that couldn't be generated with the first call.

If you don't care too much about the point being uniformly random, this solution is easy to implement and very quick. The x values are random, but the Y value is constrained if the chosen X is in the column with the rectangle, so the pixels above and below the rectangle will have a higher probability of being chosen than pizels to the left and right of the rectangle:

```
def pseudo_rand_point():        
    x = random.randint(0, screen_width-1)
    if rect_x <= x < rect_x + rect_width: 
        y = random.randint(0, screen_height-rect_height-1)
        if y >= rect_y:
            y += rect_height
    else:
        y = random.randint(0, screen_height-1)
    return (x, y)
```

Another answer was calculating the probability that the pixel is in certain regions of the screen, but their answer isn't quite correct yet. Here's a version using a similar idea, calculate the probability that the pixel is in a given region and then calculate where it is within that region:

```
valid_screen_pixels = screen_width*screen_height - rect_width * rect_height
prob_left = float(rect_x * screen_height) / valid_screen_pixels
prob_right = float((screen_width - rect_x - rect_width) * screen_height) / valid_screen_pixels
prob_above_rect = float(rect_y) / (screen_height-rect_height)
def generate_rand():
    ymin, ymax = 0, screen_height-1
    xrand = random.random()
    if xrand < prob_left:
        xmin, xmax = 0, rect_x-1
    elif xrand > (1-prob_right):
        xmin, xmax = rect_x+rect_width, screen_width-1
    else:
        xmin, xmax = rect_x, rect_x+rect_width-1
        yrand = random.random()
        if yrand < prob_above_rect:
            ymax = rect_y-1
        else:
            ymin=rect_y+rect_height
    x = random.randrange(xmin, xmax)
    y = random.randrange(ymin, ymax)
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: Something's wrong about your second solution - Code: http://pastebin.com/NYKzx3AJ Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/P9nYcQ7.png

Comment: It also seems like the pixels that were supposed to be in that strip were just shifted down by a constant amount. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/qZNryfQ.png

Comment: It's still faulty, but the first solution will work fine

Comment: I tried a slightly different and simpler approach and got the second solution working, as you said though if memory isn't an issue the first is quick and easy to understand- easy to add more invalid rectangles too as the `valid_points` list just has to be re-generated.

Comment: @Galax I like your third solution `pseudo_rand_point`. It is probably the fastest solution proposed so far and [looks random enough](http://imgur.com/m43Sv5D)

Comment: It looks OK with the given box, but is very obviously non-uniform if the box is very tall. I prefer the last solution that I based on yours- time and space efficient, uniform, and fairly understandable. It would be even simpler if there were a `random.choose()` function that took probabilities.

Comment: "the point being truly random" should be "the point being uniformly random".

Answer (score 11):

1. Partition the box into a set of sub-boxes.
2. Among the valid sub-boxes, choose which one to place your point in with probability proportional to their areas
3. Pick a random point uniformly at random from within the chosen sub-box.

[image: random sub-box]

This will generate samples from the uniform probability distribution on the valid region, based on the chain rule of conditional probability.

Comment: It looks like shortly after I posted this answer, gboffi also posted an answer that uses is essentially the same algorithm. You can use his/her code there.

Comment: @Bergi please see my post, I don't have a nice pic but I offer some [insight and code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33859020/890242)

Comment: You could merge some adjacent pairs to do with just 4 rectangles.

Comment: @miraculixx If I understand correctly your post has a slightly different algorithm. There the boxes are chosen with equal probability, whereas here I propose choosing boxes with unequal probability, based on the relative areas of the boxes.

Comment: Also, this method only needs a single random number to pick a point, because you can map the points in the interval of size `area(X)` to the points in `X`.

Answer (score 9):

This offers an O(1) approach in terms of both time and memory.

**Rationale**

The accepted answer along with some other answers seem to hinge on the necessity to generate lists of *all* possible coordinates, or recalculate until there is an acceptable solution. Both approaches take more time and memory than necessary.

Note that depending on the requirements for uniformity of coordinate generation, there are different solutions as is shown below.

**First attempt**

My approach is to randomly choose only valid coordinates around the designated box (think *left/right*, *top/bottom*), then select at random which side to choose:

```
import random
# set bounding boxes    
maxx=1000
maxy=800
blocked_box = [(500, 250), (100, 75)]
# generate left/right, top/bottom and choose as you like
def gen_rand_limit(p1, dim):
    x1, y1 = p1
    w, h = dim
    x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
    left = random.randrange(0, x1)
    right = random.randrange(x2+1, maxx-1)
    top = random.randrange(0, y1)
    bottom = random.randrange(y2, maxy-1)
    return random.choice([left, right]), random.choice([top, bottom])
# check boundary conditions are met
def check(x, y, p1, dim):
    x1, y1 = p1
    w, h = dim
    x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
    assert 0 <= x <= maxx, "0 <= x(%s) <= maxx(%s)" % (x, maxx)
    assert x1 > x or x2 < x, "x1(%s) > x(%s) or x2(%s) < x(%s)" % (x1, x, x2, x)
    assert 0 <= y <= maxy, "0 <= y(%s) <= maxy(%s)" %(y, maxy)
    assert y1 > y or y2 < y, "y1(%s) > y(%s) or y2(%s) < y(%s)" % (y1, y, y2, y)
# sample
points = []
for i in xrange(1000):
    x,y = gen_rand_limit(*blocked_box)
    check(x, y, *blocked_box)
    points.append((x,y))
```

**Results**

Given the constraints as outlined in the OP, this actually produces random coordinates (blue) around the designated rectangle (red) as desired, however leaves out any of the valid points that are outside the rectangle but fall within the respective x or y dimensions of the rectangle:

[image]

```
# visual proof via matplotlib
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
X,Y = zip(*points)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.scatter(X, Y)
p1 = blocked_box[0]
w,h = blocked_box[1]
rectangle = Rectangle(p1, w, h, fc='red', zorder=2)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis((0, maxx, 0, maxy))
ax.add_patch(rectangle)
```

**Improved**

This is easily fixed by limiting only either x or y coordinates (note that `check` is no longer valid, comment to run this part):

```
def gen_rand_limit(p1, dim):
    x1, y1 = p1
    w, h = dim
    x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
    # should we limit x or y?
    limitx = random.choice([0,1])
    limity = not limitx
    # generate x, y O(1)
    if limitx:
        left = random.randrange(0, x1)
        right = random.randrange(x2+1, maxx-1)
        x = random.choice([left, right])
        y = random.randrange(0, maxy)
    else:
        x = random.randrange(0, maxx)
        top = random.randrange(0, y1)
        bottom = random.randrange(y2, maxy-1)
        y = random.choice([top, bottom])
    return x, y
```

[image]

**Adjusting the random bias**

As pointed out in the comments this solution suffers from a bias given to points outside the rows/columns of the rectangle. The following fixes that *in principle* by giving each coordinate the same probability:

```
def gen_rand_limit(p1, dim):
    x1, y1 = p1Final solution -
    w, h = dim
    x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
    # generate x, y O(1)
    # --x
    left = random.randrange(0, x1)
    right = random.randrange(x2+1, maxx)
    withinx = random.randrange(x1, x2+1)
    # adjust probability of a point outside the box columns
    # a point outside has probability (1/(maxx-w)) v.s. a point inside has 1/w
    # the same is true for rows. adjupx/y adjust for this probability 
    adjpx = ((maxx - w)/w/2)
    x = random.choice([left, right] * adjpx + [withinx])
    # --y
    top = random.randrange(0, y1)
    bottom = random.randrange(y2+1, maxy)
    withiny = random.randrange(y1, y2+1)
    if x == left or x == right:
        adjpy = ((maxy- h)/h/2)
        y = random.choice([top, bottom] * adjpy + [withiny])
    else:
        y = random.choice([top, bottom])
    return x, y
```

The following plot has 10'000 points to illustrate the uniform placement of points (the points overlaying the box' border are due to point size).

Disclaimer: Note that this plot places the red box in the very middle such that`top/bottom`, `left/right` have the same probability among each other. The adjustment thus is relative to the blocking box, but not for all areas of the graph. A final solution requires to adjust the probabilities for each of these separately.

[image]

**Simpler solution, yet slightly modified problem**

It turns out that adjusting the probabilities for different areas of the coordinate system is quite tricky. After some thinking I came up with a slightly modified approach:

Realizing that on any 2D coordinate system blocking out a rectangle divides the area into N sub-areas (N=8 in the case of the question) where a valid coordinate can be chosen. Looking at it this way, we can define the valid sub-areas as boxes of coordinates. Then we can choose a box at random and a coordinate at random from within that box:

```
def gen_rand_limit(p1, dim):
    x1, y1 = p1
    w, h = dim
    x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
    # generate x, y O(1)
    boxes = (
       ((0,0),(x1,y1)),   ((x1,0),(x2,y1)),    ((x2,0),(maxx,y1)),
       ((0,y1),(x1,y2)),                       ((x2,y1),(maxx,y2)),
       ((0,y2),(x1,maxy)), ((x1,y2),(x2,maxy)), ((x2,y2),(maxx,maxy)),
    )
    box = boxes[random.randrange(len(boxes))]
    x = random.randrange(box[0][0], box[1][0])
    y = random.randrange(box[0][1], box[1][1])
    return x, y
```

Note this is not generalized as the blocked box may not be in the middle hence `boxes` would look different. As this results in each box chosen with the same probability, we get the same *number* of points in each box. Obviously the densitiy is higher in smaller boxes:

[image]

If the requirement is to generate a uniform distribution among all possible coordinates, the solution is to calculate `boxes` such that each box is about the same size as the blocking box. YMMV

Comment: It seems the second graph has fewer points placed in the same row or column as the box

Comment: @NeonWizard yes, I suppose that's due to the probability of a point on either column or row of the box being lower than the probability of being outside the box, namely (for columns) 0.5 * 1/maxx v.s. 0.5 * ((1/leftx) + (1/rightx)) and simliarly for rows). That's quite a rough guess so I may have the details wrong here. Here's an example with [10'000 points](http://imgur.com/ii3RsUi) that shows the same effect.

Comment: It wasn't stated very explicitly in the question, but I think the point that is  generated should be truly random, with each point having the same probability as every other point of being chosen.

Comment: @miraculixx I don't think it is correct yet, using smaller plotted pixels I see a much higher density of points above the rectangle than below (plotting the points using pygame so the Y axis is reversed, you would have a lower density of points above the rectangle).

Comment: I've added a similar solution to my answer, that I think is correct. It's a bit simpler, and uses fewer random numbers.

Comment: @Galax your new solution looks promising as you adjust for probabilities on the "outset". However, the solution is [not correct](http://imgur.com/3Jvapoz)

Comment: @miraculixx I think you are drawing the red box in a different place than is specified in the question- you changed the box position between your second and third attempts.

Comment: Here's the plot that I generate get with your final solution, definitely not uniform: http://imgur.com/d8wpHOH

Comment: @Galax just checked that. It turns out you are right. To my defense that was by accident -- I wanted to see how the probabilities were influenced by positioning/resizing the box and then left this in the plot. Added a disclaimer to state as much. Also note my last attempt which when generalized will result in a uniform distribution, or rather it raises the question of what is really the requirement...

Comment: "calculate boxes such that each box is about the same size as the blocking box" is quite a strange and restrictive requirement. I like your general approach but it's a shame that it couldn't produce a 'random' uniform distribution of all valid points. You should note in your answer that your 10,000 point plot is not uniform, it only appears to be because of the large dots (see my imgur link above).

Comment: @Galax it's a trade-off... generating the list of boxes can be just as expensive as generating lists of valid coordinates, or even more so. ultimately the 'correct' solution depends on the exact requirements

Comment: Well, regarding your last solution:  you could give different probabilities to different boxes proportional to their area, which is pretty easy to compute, and choose among them based on that, then you should obtain a much better distribution.

Answer (score 8):

I've already posted a different answer that I still like, as it is simple and
clear, and not necessarily slow... at any rate it's not exactly what the OP asked for.

I thought about it and I devised an algorithm for solving the OP's problem within their constraints:

1. partition the screen in 9 rectangles around and comprising the "hole".
2. consider the 8 rectangles ("tiles") around the central hole"
3. for each tile, compute the origin (x, y), the height and the area in pixels
4. compute the cumulative sum of the areas of the tiles, as well as the total area of the tiles
5. for each extraction, choose a random number between 0 and the total area of the tiles (inclusive and exclusive)
6. using the cumulative sums determine in which tile the random pixel lies
7. using `divmod` determine the column and the row (dx, dy) in the tile
8. using the origins of the tile in the screen coordinates, compute the random pixel  in screen coordinates.

To implement the ideas above, in which there is an initialization phase in which we compute static data and a phase in which we repeatedly use those data, the natural data structure is a class, and here it is my implementation

```
from random import randrange

class make_a_hole_in_the_screen():

    def __init__(self, screen, hole_orig, hole_sizes):
        xs, ys = screen
        x, y = hole_orig
        wx, wy = hole_sizes
        tiles = [(_y,_x*_y) for _x in [x,wx,xs-x-wx] for _y in [y,wy,ys-y-wy]]
        self.tiles = tiles[:4] + tiles[5:]
        self.pixels = [tile[1] for tile in self.tiles]
        self.total = sum(self.pixels)
        self.boundaries = [sum(self.pixels[:i+1]) for i in range(8)]
        self.x = [0,    0,    0,
                  x,          x,
                  x+wx, x+wx, x+wx]
        self.y = [0,    y,    y+wy,
                  0,          y+wy,
                  0,    y,    y+wy]

    def choose(self):
        n = randrange(self.total)
        for i, tile in enumerate(self.tiles):
            if n < self.boundaries[i]: break
        n1 = n - ([0]+self.boundaries)[i]
        dx, dy = divmod(n1,self.tiles[i][0])
        return self.x[i]+dx, self.y[i]+dy
```

To test the correctness of the implementation, here it is a rough check that I
run on `python 2.7`,

```
drilled_screen = make_a_hole_in_the_screen((200,100),(30,50),(20,30))
for i in range(1000000):
    x, y = drilled_screen.choose()
    if 30<=x<50 and 50<=y<80: print "***", x, y
    if x<0 or x>=200 or y<0 or y>=100: print "+++", x, y
```

A possible optimization consists in using a bisection algorithm to find the relevant tile in place of the simpler linear search that I've implemented.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the generation of random you want to avoid, rather than the loop, you can do the following:

1. Generate a pair of random *floating point* coordinates in [0,1]
2. Scale the coordinates to give a point in the outer rectangle.
3. If your point is outside the inner rectangle, return it
4. Rescale to map the inner rectangle to the outer rectangle
5. Goto step 3

This will work best if the inner rectangle is small as compared to the outer rectangle. And it should probably be limited to only going through the loop some maximum number of times before generating new random and trying again.